# VUE/ NUXT SSR add query string to URL without reloading - Performance issues and sluggish scroll

Tags: performance, vue.js, query-string, vue-router, nuxt.js

Fighting with this for a couple of days already and can't find a solution.

I have a Nuxt app that displays some items + a set of filter buttons to hide them with a nice animation.

I'm pushing a query to the URL so users can share the link. But I get a heavy performance hit while pushing the query. Scrolling becomes sluggish and the animations stutter for almost a second.

I have tried 3 different approaches as I thought it might be due to some internal reloading... the $router.push function, window.history.pushState and window.history.replaceState. The result is the same.

I set up a clean Nuxt project without filtering/animations and it shows the same slowdown. I then tried to set up a sharable CodeSandbox and the effect is much weaker there! Added some animation to make it comparable, but as I said the effect is hardly visible, so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-star-s505h

The same set up on my local machine and on my production server shows a massive slow down.
I tried it in dev mode and in production mode, no difference.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's SSR related? Because my first guess would be it is not. Anyways, it currently looks like you gave us no way of reproducing the issue, therefore no way of testing any potential fix. Right?

Comment: Yes, it's a guess at the moment. It's hard for me to pin down the issue as it's seems to be fine on codesandbox. I was hoping somebody did run into the same issue before, or has the motivation to set up the repo as on codesandbox on their a local machine with Nuxt SSR. If the same issue pops up I would post it as an issue on nuxt's github.

Comment: I downloaded your example from CodeSandbox and ran it locally, but didn't see any lag.

Comment: @DelenaMalan did you try to scroll?

Comment: @flobb I did indeed.

Comment: Not sure if I'm allowed to post a video like this but here is how it looks like on my local machine. And it's the same effect I see on my production server which is another machine :( edit: link https://filebin.net/rjommr1uzx2r19is

Comment: @DelenaMalan Thanks for your feedback. And you created the nuxt project with the CLI npx create-nuxt-app with universal mode? If so I guess I'll have to do some more digging on my side. At least I know it hast to do something with my setup...

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint but web development debugging is the exact opposite of what you seem to think it is. It's the process of ruling out possible causes of a particular behavior until the root cause is clear. This is not done by guessing, but by testing. Which is impossible without a [mcve]. As in, even if I do have a hunch on the cause of a particular issue, I almost never consider providing an answer until I'm able to test my supposition.

Comment: No, disappointment there @tao, only with your last comment as I have provided you with the best I can for you to reproduce the issue. I know I'm wasting your time in case it turns out the issue is on my side, but I have tried 2 different machines with several different setups. The result on codesandbox confused me, so I tried to get an oppinion here. Thanks for your time. I understand your frustration but try to keep your criticism constructive.

Comment: First of all, I have no frustration whatsoever. And second, I don't understand which part of my comments you found not constructive. I can't think of any way to be more constructive than telling you exactly what's preventing others from helping you. Anyway, the reason why I still linger around is because I'm fairly experienced and passionate about animations, about rendering performance and about Vue. I therefore am more likely to be able to help on your question than on others. If you find a way to make it answerable, that is. I'll keep checking for updates. Cheers!

Comment: @tao constructive means that if we engage in a discussion we will move towards a solution. Not constructive means not only your time is wasted but also mine. ---

My initial post provides two problems: 1. How can I solve my issue and 2. Is the repo reproducing the issue for somebody else? If so, I provided a mwe. If not, I have to do further testing for an issue that looked simple. If a build produces different results in different environments, things can be very frustrating.   

Simple as that.